# Is the "os" module not subject to import shadowing?

Tags: python

In Python, one tries to avoid module name conflicts with the standard library, though Python 3 makes this better by getting rid of implicit relative imports in packages. So I was doing this intentionally, to test my understanding, and got a surprise.

```
test/
    __init__.py
    test.py:
        import os
        import string
    os.py:
        print("os")
    string.py:
        print("string")
```

Running from the parent directory:

```
$ python2 -m test.test
os
string
```

Implicit relative imports shadowing the system modules, as expected.

```
$ python3 -m test.test
```

Absolute imports in Python 3, as expected.

```
$ python test/test.py
string
$ python3 test/test.py
string
```

Huh? Why doesn't the "os" in the script directory shadow the system one?

(I figured this out upon typing the question, but I'll post anyway in case anyone else wonders.)

Answer (score 3):

At startup, `os` is already loaded by the interpreter, just not available in the globals of the script/module. Much like when a module has already been imported somewhere in a package, but isn't available to a different submodule until you import it there.

In fact there are quite a few modules like this; try `python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.modules)))"`.